# Connection refused trying to get account info in Solana

Tags: anchor, solana

```
solana account <address>
```

When I get account info, I have this error:

```
Error: RPC request error: cluster version query failed: error sending request for url (http://localhost:8899/): error trying to connect: tcp connect error: Connection refused (os error 111)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is indicating that the CLI RpcClient can not communicate with the Solana validator.

This is usually caused by not having `solana-test-validator` running in another terminal. Many make the mistake of thinking that the localhost is running the validator all the time... it's not.

In one terminal do: `solana-test-validator` which will startup up the local validator
Open a second terminal and do `solana account` - This will return account info for the default keypair

Comment: What about if we want to interact with devnet, do we still need to run that?

Answer (score 0):

It's a network connection problem.
I use **ubuntu 20.04**, I was using **windscribe VPN** because my location and got the error, now I'm using **psiphon VPN** and it's working fine.